# Android SQLite Like query for each word containing keyword

Tags: android-sqlite

E.g: I have 1 word for search the data. And the word is 'ayam'.

And this is my query:

```
select nama_product from product where nama_product like %a%
```

It works fine. But it shows the record that I dont want to be shown. This is the result:

- ayam bakar
- daging ayam
- bayam hijau
- daun bayam

The first and the second result is okay. But the third and the last that I don't want to be shown.

Because I want to show 'ayam' not "b'ayam'"

How do I handle this?

In MySql I'm using this:

```
select nama_product
  from product
 where nama_product regexp '(^| )ayam( |$)';
```

But I'm confused to using like / GLOB.

Comment: SQLite3 supports regex operator. Don't go for like.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
SELECT nama_product FROM product WHERE nama_product LIKE 'a%' OR nama_product like '% a%'
```

Comment: Does it apply with search keyword containing 3 Words or more ?

Comment: for three it will but more then 3 characters i don't know